# Why echo $(crontab -l) outputs current working directory listing and only then the content of crontab file itself?

Tags: bash, cron, crontab

So if `cwd` is the `/tmp` now:

```
crontab -l
> #min hour day mon dow  command
> * * * * * /usr/local/bin/growlnotify -t 'helloTitle' -m 'helloMessage' -n 'myApp' -sw
```

**but:**

```
echo $(crontab -l)
> #min hour day mon dow  command 0004d519be91d 0004d519d798b launch-0NKnNe launch-NdhkpV
launch-bqJRD2 launch-zac20v launchd-276.rbWQ6r 0004d519be91d 0004d519d798b launch-0NKnNe
launch-NdhkpV launch-bqJRD2 launch-zac20v launchd-276.rbWQ6r 0004d519be91d 0004d519d798
launch-0NKnNe launch-NdhkpV launch-bqJRD2 launch-zac20v launchd-276.rbWQ6r 0004d519be91d 
0004d519d798b launch-0NKnNe launch-NdhkpV launch-bqJRD2 launch-zac20v launchd-276.rbWQ6r 
0004d519be91d 0004d519d798b launch-0NKnNe launch-NdhkpV launch-bqJRD2 launch-zac20v 
launchd-276.rbWQ6r /usr/local/bin/growlnotify -t 'helloTitle' -m 'helloMessage' -n 'myApp' -sw
```

so **first** line + **/tmp** content + **last** line of the crontab

Why such a behavior?
I need the `$(crontab -l)` for `if [[ $(crontab -l | grep "^...$") =~ "^...$"]]`

Answer (score 1):

You get the file list because “crontab -l” returns star characters (*) that get then interpreted as glob characters.

I suggest you use 'set -f' in your shell script around your test to turn of glob interpretation:

```
set -f
if $(crontab -l | grep -q "^...$"); then
  # your stuff
fi
set +f
```

Comment: I knew it! Thank you very much for the `set -f`!

Comment: one could make also `echo "$(crontab -l)"`, helps too

Comment: Double-quotes is a much better way to solve this.

Comment: This is a syntax error -- it tries to execute the output from `grep` and fails if it is not a valid command.

Answer (score 0):

Improving on the previous answer, there is no value in running the commands in a subshell.

```
if crontab -l | grep -q '^...$'; then
    your stuff
fi
```

Just to emphasize, this avoids the need for `set -f` since only the output code from `grep` is being examined.